# PHP not pushing LONGTEXT field from my database table to my array

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with a field of type `LONGTEXT`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM openings WHERE  shortlisted = 'NO' ORDER BY fullName asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $final[] = array( 
        "status" => "200", 
        "message" => "Applicants information fetched successfully"
    );
    foreach ($result as $row) { 
        $cv = $row['cover_letter'];
        $final[]= array ( 
            "coverletter" => $cv 
        );
    }
    echo json_encode($final);
}
```

But I get no response, if I change this line `"coverletter" => $cv` to `"coverletter" => gettype($cv)`

I get a response of type String.

Comment: You need to `fetch` the `$result`.

Comment: how can I fetch the result @chris85?

Comment: If using mysqli see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late to the party here... but I had a similar issue where I was calling a PHP script via AJAX to retrieve database information and push it to a webpage. However the query was failing anytime I included the longtext field.

After scouring the web I figured out the issue, which had to do with character encoding. Simply adding the following line after my SELECT statement fixed the issue immediately:

```
mysqli_query($db_conn, 'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

Hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score -1):

I think you are making mistake in the code .

try this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM openings WHERE  shortlisted = 'NO' ORDER BY 
fullName asc";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 
if ($result->num_rows > 0){
     $final[] = array( 
    "status" => "200", 
    "message" => "Applicants information fetched successfully" 
     );
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  
    {
       $cv = $row['cover_letter'];
       $final[]= array ( 
       "coverletter" => $cv 
                  );
    }
    echo json_encode($final);
 }
```

i have updated the code since ,in your code you were not fetching the result inspite you were directly trying to get the row on the result obj which is wrong.

Comment: I have tried it, still doesn't work,  `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  {} ` is also the same as `foreach ($result as $row) { } `

Comment: what is the output of $row can you just var_dump($row)  in while loop

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` won't work with `mysqli`. @CWilliams What driver are you using.

Comment: no that is not same you need to fetch the result  my calling mysqli_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_assoc  to get the output in associative array.

Comment: @shashikantkuswaha  
 Here is  a sample response using var_dump ($row) below :   `array(4) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(4) "3360"
  ["fullName"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["age"]=>
  string(2) "22"
  ["cover_letter"]=>
  string(194) "You should hire me because i will be a contributive  and positive worker to your organizations.. Thanks"
}`

Comment: Yes so you can get the cover_letter using                
  $row->cover_letter.      ... Like.                         $cv = $row->cover_letter;
       $final[]= array ( 
       "coverletter" => $cv 
                  );